# Program Compatibility

Tags: windows, wine, games

I just installed Fifa manager 13 on ubuntu 13.04, but it doesn't work because I need to change the program compatibility before it runs. How do I do that in ubuntu??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WineHQ Applications Database is a database that rates the compatibility of Windows applications running on Linux using Wine. FIFA Manager 13 isn't even rated on the WineHQ Applications Database. The previous version, FIFA Manager 12, is listed [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13613) however, and it is rated as Garbage, so you'll probably have to play it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

FiFa Manager 13 is a windows application, and can't run under Ubuntu natively.  In order to be able to run it, you need to install [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

To install Wine, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I did that but it still doesn't run. I just get a black screen.